# calculate depth from point cloud xyz

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a single point in  PointCloud2 ('sensor_msgs/PointCloud2),  a value of
x,y,z. I want to know how to calculate the depth to that point.

For example from point (57,341)

I get (x,y,z)=(-0.6895000338554382, 0.2666066884994507, 1.3790000677108765)

How i calculate the depth from this information ? It is only z value? what the meaning of negative at x?

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141741/calculate-depth-from-point-cloud-xyz/) by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DragonZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/91275/dragonz/) on 2021-12-09**:
How did you get the value of x,y,z from PointCloud2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The x,y,z values of a point cloud point give the position relative to the frame defined in the message header. E.g. the Kinect frame. If you want to calculate the distance between your camera's lens and a specific point you only need to determine the length of the point's vector. vec_length = square_root(x^2 + y^2 + z^2).

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on 2014-03-19**:
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The below code:

- Subscribed to
  `/camera/depth/image_raw` rostopic,
- Convert ROS image to OpenCV image
- Get image dimension
- Get global max and min value,
- Get depth value at specific point,

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;

static const uint32_t MY_ROS_QUEUE_SIZE = 1000;

void imgcb(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    try {
        cv_bridge::CvImageConstPtr cv_ptr;
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg);

        //get image dimension once
        static bool runOnce = true;
        if (runOnce){
            cout << "Image dimension (Row,Col): " << cv_ptr->image.rows << " x " << cv_ptr->image.cols << endl;
            runOnce = false;
        }

        //get global max depth value
        double max = 0.0;
        cv::minMaxLoc(cv_ptr->image, 0, &max, 0, 0);
        std::cout << "Max value: " << max << endl;

        //get global min depth value
        double min = 0.0;
        cv::minMaxLoc(cv_ptr->image, &min, &max, 0, 0);
        std::cout << "Min value: " << min << endl;

        //get depth value at a point
        float distanceVal = cv_ptr->image.at<float>(100, 100);
        std::cout << "Distance value: " << distanceVal << "m" << endl;

    } catch (const cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "foo");

    std::cout << "Getting Image depth value!" << std::endl;

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("camera/depth/image_raw", MY_ROS_QUEUE_SIZE, imgcb);

    ros::spin();

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) with karma: 115 on 2021-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1